# How to setup "Docs for Xcode" (for use with Xcode 5)

Tags: xcode5

Newbie here,

Just got xcode 5 for the first time. My understanding is that xcode 5 does not allow for documentation from third parties but there is a workaround using an app on the app store called Docs for Xcode. Ironically however "Docs for Xcode" has no documentation so I'm not sure how to set it up.

Here's what I figured out so far:

1. After the initial setup where you pick which folder "Docs for Xcode" is going to save
2. Go to cocoadocs.org
3. Search for the library your looking for
4. Click xcode logo on top right
5. Click add to xcode
6. Your browser will import it into "Docs for Xcode"

However, I haven't figured out how to get Xcode to look in the directory that "Docs for Xcode" saves into. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

It works the other way around, you need to grant access to Xcode's folder (which is `~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/`). This should be preselected when granting access.

(I made this more clear in 1.0.3, sorry for the confusion.)

Comment: ~/Library is hidden and doesn't show in the `Please click Grant Access` dialog window. Perform `chflags nohidden ~/Library` in a terminal window in order to be able to drill into it.  
You will also need to create the full directory tree in the terminal window.

Comment: @gone: This is not true. It very much does show (~/Library being hidden is irrelevant if you direct `NSOpenPanel` to a subfolder!) *if DocSets already exists* (and if it doesn't, you can't "drill into ~/Library" to select it, because it's not there). That's why the app instructs you how to create the directory, with the exact command to use, if your Xcode install is so fresh it has no Apple docsets updates in it yet (a rare occurrence in the first place).

Comment: Simply put, ~/Library was not available to drill into in the Grant Access dialog, and thus I couldn't get to the desired folder.  After I used chflags, it worked fine, though I had to create some of the sub-folders.

Comment: @gone Again, you wouldn't *have* to "drill into" if the DocSets folder existed already. The app would *preselect* the *sub*folder for you, *regardless* of ~/Library hidden status. That ~/Library is hidden matters *only when viewing ~* — and if DocSets exists, you never have to, because you're several levels deeper. That's simply how Finder and `NSOpenPanel` work. You clearly don't believe me, but well: try it!

Comment: I've described the steps I needed to perform.  Enough said.